# Refactor same method used within an object - javascript

Tags: javascript

The code is as follows

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: ({ defaultTheme }) =>
        defaultTheme ? theme.swatch.green[600] : theme.palette.common.black,
    },
    backgroundColor: ({ defaultTheme }) =>
      defaultTheme ? theme.swatch.green[600] : theme.palette.common.black,
  },
}));

const _classes = useStyles({ defaultTheme });
```

As it can be seen, backgroundColor function is repeated multiple times. Is there a way to refactor this **within the useStyles object?**

Comment: create that arrow function separate outside and pass required params to that function and use it here

Comment: backgroundColor is the same then why you are adding background color on Hover??

Comment: button is having a default color for hover. I want to override that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper function inside the `makeStyles` callback argument like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
    const backgroundColor = ({ defaultTheme }) =>
        defaultTheme ? theme.swatch.green[600] : theme.palette.common.black;
    
    return {
        root: {
            cursor: "pointer",
                color: theme.palette.common.white,
                "&:hover": {
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor
            },
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor
        },
    }
});
```

You can use ES6 object literal shorthand to make this more concise. (Note the function name is the same as the object key so you can use just `backgroundColor` instead of `backgroundColor: backgroundColor`):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
    const backgroundColor = ({ defaultTheme }) =>
        defaultTheme ? theme.swatch.green[600] : theme.palette.common.black;

    return {
        root: {
            cursor: "pointer",
            color: theme.palette.common.white,
            "&:hover": {
                backgroundColor
            },
            backgroundColor
        },
    }
});
```

Or you can create the helper function outside of the hook and pass it the `theme` object as an argument:

```
const backgroundColor = (theme) => ({ defaultTheme }) =>
    defaultTheme ? theme.swatch.green[600] : theme.palette.common.black;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        cursor: "pointer",
        color: theme.palette.common.white,
        "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor(theme)
        },
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor(theme)
    },
}));
```

Note: in the last example I used currying so the `backgroundColor` function is a function that takes the `theme` as parameter and returns another function that will take props as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
    const getBackgrounColor = ({ defaultTheme }) =>
        defaultTheme ? theme.swatch.green[600] : theme.palette.common.black;
    
    return {
        root: {
            cursor: "pointer",
            color: theme.palette.common.white,
            "&:hover": {
                backgroundColor: getBackgrounColor,
            },
            backgroundColor: getBackgrounColor,
        },
    };
});
```

Comment: I would do this too, but OP is asking if it's possible to do in the return object, no?